# Parsing XML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, loops

So I'm trying to parse an XML document in C# using the XmlDocument Class. So far I've successfully been able to load data from the first node, called `<map>`.

```
    public void read()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:\\map.xml");

        parseMap(doc);
    }


    private void parseDoc(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlNode map = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/map");

        int mapWidth = Convert.ToInt16(map.Attributes["width"].InnerText);
        int mapHeight = Convert.ToInt16(map.Attributes["height"].InnerText);
        int tileWidth = Convert.ToInt16(map.Attributes["tilewidth"].InnerText);
        int tileHeight = Convert.ToInt16(map.Attributes["tileheight"].InnerText);

        Console.Write("Map width: " + mapWidth + "\nMap height: " + mapHeight +
            "\nTile width: " + tileWidth + "\nTile height: " + tileHeight);

        int tilesetsCount = map.SelectNodes("tileset").Count;
        Console.Write("\nAmount of tilesets: " + tilesetsCount);
        foreach (XmlNode tileset in map.ChildNodes)
        {
            int firstgid = Convert.ToInt16(tileset.Attributes["firstgid"].InnerText);
            string name = tileset.Attributes["name"].InnerText;
            int tilesetTileWidth = Convert.ToInt16(tileset.Attributes["tilewidth"].InnerText);
            int tilesetTileHeight = Convert.ToInt16(tileset.Attributes["tileheight"].InnerText);

            foreach(XmlNode image in tileset.ChildNodes)
            {
                imageWidth = Convert.ToInt16(image.Attributes["width"].InnerText);
                imageHeight = Convert.ToInt16(image.Attributes["height"].InnerText);
            }

            List<Tileset> tilesetList = new List<Tileset>();
            tilesetList.Add(new Tileset(firstgid, name, tilesetTileWidth, tilesetTileHeight, 
                imageWidth, imageHeight));
        }
}
```

But then I run into a problem, my XML document will include several `<tileset>` tags; so logically I concluded I had to do a loop (the first one).

When I try compiling and running the code, visual studios tells me that a *"NullReferenceException was unhandled"* while pointing at the first line inside the foreach loop.

So what's going on here?

Edit1:I couldn't blockquote my XML, so I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qW967heQ

Edit2: In reply to using LINQ; I did try it, but it just ended with me being unable to access the data I retrieved from the XML, like sure I could log it with the ordinary {0} tag, but I couldn't assign the value to a variable. I'm not too experienced so I'm sorry if I seem to be missing something obvious.

Comment: put your xml to help you

Comment: It's hard to tell whats wrong with your code without seeing data you are trying to parse

Comment: Which `foreach` loop? You've got two. Also, do you *have* to use `XmlDocument`? LINQ to XML is much simpler. If you could post a sample of the XML and fix your code formatting that would help too.

Comment: Not only that, you are stuffing so much dang code into the 'first line' that there are several places you could get null reference exceptions. Let me give you a tip. Don't stuff so much code into nested expressions like that. It makes it hard to debug.

Comment: I haven't thought about that before Johnson, thank you for the tip. But I still have no clue on how to fix this. I added my XML code and fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the foreach loop you access `map.ChildNodes`. This returns the `tileset` nodes but also `layer` nodes. You then try to access the `InnerText` property of the non-existing `firstgid` attribute of the `layer` nodes.

Instead of `map.ChildNodes` you can use `map.SelectNodes("tileset")` to filter for `tileset` nodes.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Do you have any clue where I can read more about this? I notice that I lack in basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

may be this help you

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

xDoc.Load(@"D:\Map.xml");
        parseXML(xDoc);



private void parseXML(XmlDocument xdoc) {
        try {

            var enumXMLnode = from xelement in xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("tileset").Cast<XmlElement>()
                              select xelement;
            foreach (XmlElement innerData in enumXMLnode) {
                MessageBox.Show(innerData.InnerXml);
            }
        }
        catch { 

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can directly jump to any node